# 404 handler getting "Handle is not initialized" exception

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am using the approach below to handle 404 errors on my sites. This has worked for a long time but suddenly within the last month I am getting a "Handle is not initialized" exception with a number of sites on our dedicated server (some still work, and on development machine it works). Anyone have any thoughts?

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/default.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

On default.aspx page:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack && Request.Url.ToString().Contains("?404;"))
  {
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/");
    Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl("<base href='" + Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "'/>"));
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    Util.DisplayAlert("The page you are looking for no longer exists. If you navigated to this page by clicking a link within this site please <a href='/contact.aspx'>contact us</a> to let us know.");
  }
}
```

Exception details:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Handle is not initialized.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.FromIntPtr(IntPtr value)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.GetManagedPrincipalHandler(IntPtr pRootedObjects)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdGetPrincipal(IntPtr pHandler, IntPtr& pToken, IntPtr& ppAuthType, Int32& pcchAuthType, IntPtr& ppUserName, Int32& pcchUserName, IntPtr& pManagedPrincipal)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetUserPrincipal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.SynchronizeVariables(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

Comment: I don't know *why* this is happening, but I did find that by disabling runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests the problem disappears. I'm going to try filing it on connect to see if the cause is forthcoming.

Comment: Thanks others for confirming they're experiencing the issue as well. Thanks danludwig for mentioning about it working if you are signed in indeed that is why I was getting "some [sites] still work, and on development machine it works". Since this is starting to sound like it's only started after some patch, I've filed this issue at Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/732494/asp-net-httperrors-handle-is-not-initialized

Comment: @PhilipStears Did you end up filing it on connect? If you did posting the url would be appreciated, I couldn't find your report doing a bing search so filed a new report linked above but had better indicate mine is a duplicate if you did. Thanks.

Comment: This is an ASP.NET 4.5-specific code path.  Do you know if the server is running the //BUILD/ release (Sep '11) or the Beta release (Mar '12)?

Comment: @Levi, it's running the beta release (the build release was never installed). This is also happening with websites targeting 4.0. I can't remember if this started happening before .NET 4.5 was installed.

Comment: We have tracked down the root cause and are queuing a fix.  The root cause wasn't even that sexy - just a missing null check. :(  Thanks for the report, and sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @Levi Thanks heaps for looking into it, and for the fix.

Comment: @Levi- Has the fix been released? It appears that I'm entirely up to date but I'm seeing the issue.

Comment: @Levi- Disregard. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735533/calling-server-transferrequest-inside-httpapplication-endrequest-event-throws-invalidoperationexception-handle-is-not-initialized

Comment: Wanted to followup on this. I'm experiencing this problem in a MVC3 app I'm working on. The connect issue listed is set to resolved duplicate but it doesn't list which issue it was actually tied to. Did this fix make it into the April Bug Fix release? I installed the patch to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59641/levi): We have tracked down the root cause and are queuing a fix.
>
> [Andrew McLachlan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341542/andrew-mclachlan) Confirmed as fixed in .NET 4.5 RC

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem but haven't found a solution yet. I have confirmed that the problem is caused by setting the StatusCode or Status properties on the response, it affects IIS 7 and IIS Express but not Cassini which makes sense given the stack trace.

I'll keep investigating.

Edit: No luck in finding a solution. I posted the same question on the IIS forums: http://forums.iis.net/p/1187959/2016914.aspx#2016914

Edit 2: Confirmed as fixed in .NET 4.5 RC.

Comment: I also just noticed this is happening. For some reason the 404 works when there is a user signed in, but getting "Handle is not initialized" when users are not signed in.